# Global Leaderboards for Windows Phone 8 XAML games

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

How to implement Leader Boards in Windows Phone 8 games developed in XAML and C#. Apple has a game center. Is there anything available for Windows Phone 8 like that? Users should be able to submit their scores using their live account.